# Why does ant build fail with sudo even though it succeeds when run as root user?

Tags: linux, apache, ant, java, redhat

I am compiling an Android app on server with java build tool ant.

When I run the following as root user the build succeeds:

```
export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/ant
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANT_HOME}/bin
cd /path/to/android/file
/usr/local/ant/bin/ant release
```

However, when I run the following as netuser (or any other user which I've tested):

```
export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/ant
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANT_HOME}/bin
cd /path/to/android/file
sudo /usr/local/ant/bin/ant release
```

I get the following error:

```
BUILD FAILED
/path/to/android/file/build.xml:83: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/usr/share/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:206: Class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.And doesn't support the nested "matches" element.
```

I have tried changing sudoers file to even give netuser all permissions with netuser ALL=(ALL) ALL but I get same results... Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: 1) Post relevant part of your build.xml.  2) run ant with -debug and see output for some hints.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you're not picking up the environment variables when running as `sudo`.  The error message suggests it is using an older version of the Ant tasks than you expect.

To see if this is the case, try the following (after the exports) and see if it is what you are expecting:

```
sudo env
```

To preserve the environment variables, either modify the `sudoers` file or use the `-E` option.